# Excel - Find the correct value out of multiple

Tags: excel-formula

I'm currently trying to extract a set of values corresponding to some other but can't succeed.

On my sheet, I have 2 columns (Country (C) / online(D))

[Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBBfv.png)

There are multiple values.
In columns F and G, I display the results.

I'm using a formula with INDEX/MATCH to do this but the problem it only takes into account the first value found (so for country BEL, first value is "yes", it will show "yes" in column G). My formula is

```
=INDEX(D2:D8,MATCH(F2:F4,C2:C8,0))
```

What I'd like is if for BEL there are "yes" and "no" values, the result will show me "no". so "yes" is a default value and if there are "yes" and "no", since there is a different value for BEL, it will show this other value and give this

[Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK1Kr.png)

any idea how to do this ?

Hope it's clear.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COUNTIFS to get the number of matches where ONLINE = "no" for each country, then use that as an input to an IF statement that will output "no" if the count of "no" in the table is > 0

here is a formula to get started:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,"=no",A:A,E4)>0,"no","yes")
```

COL A has the Countries, B the Online state, and E is the summary section

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. I managed to work something out of this. I used the COUNTIFS part only in a column for "no" and in another for "yes". Then used conditional formatting to show colors related to what i need. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You're welcome! if possible, please share the modified formula that worked for you and mark the selected answer so that others can lean from your question.

Comment: Hello, sure, sorry. so what i did (adapted to my example above) in cell G2 is =COUNTIFS(D:D,"no",C:C,F2). this for the "no", same for the "yes" in cell H2. so it will count the number of "yes" and "no" and put the result in 2 columns. then i used a conditional formatting to add some colors according to the result like ...=$H2:$H4>0 ...then it becomes green